# Query is not working with promise for Dynamo DB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo db table where I was able to insert data using node js via lambda. I am able to query from the console and I am also able to query using the cli. When using query with promise its erroring out with invoke error. Its not throwing any specific errors. IF I remove promise and run I can see that connection is successful to the db. I also tried  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
":name": {"S":id}
},

even hard coding the value for id and same issue. What am I doing wrong??

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk"
const dyanamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" })
export const checkIFIDExist = async (id) => {

    try {
        const params = {
            ProjectionExpression: "String1, String2",
            IndexName: "String2",
            KeyConditionExpression: "String2 = :name",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":name": id
            },
            TableName: 'my-table',
        }  
        const data = await dynamoDB.query(params).promise()
        console.log("Data:", data)
        return "success"
    }catch (err) {
        throw new Error (`Failed query for ${id} `, err)
    }

}
```

Error:

```
2022-08-16T20:24:09.210Z    c2e0c093-2719-48b8-b0bb-4f38de3ac7b6    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Failed query for OE0K0I ",
    "stack": [
        "Error: Failed query for OE0K0I ",
        "    at checkIFStepFunctionIDExists (file:///var/task/src/dynamo-query.js:24:15)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/src/index.js:11:19)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `err` when this happens? Print it out and add it to your post.

Comment: Do you really have an index named `String2` ? I mean, index isn't just supposed to be a field-name of course. I may be stating the obvious. But just to make sure.

Comment: Yes string2 is an index

Comment: @jarmod the err content is what I have above. I know it doesn't give much info and this is what threw me off. I had implemented same query in my other project and my old teammates are still using it. I even referenced old repo for comparison and there is no syntax difference

Comment: Please print `err` and add it to the post. Also, I think you may need to correct your use of [Error()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error). Instead of simply passing `err` as the 2nd parameter, I think it should be `{ cause: err }`.

Comment: `2022-08-17T19:05:07.833Z undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Named export 'IoTEvents' not found. The requested module 'aws-sdk' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.\nCommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:\n\nimport pkg from 'aws-sdk';\nconst { IoTEvents } = pkg;\n","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Named export 'IoTEvents' not found.`

Comment: Looks like you may have some dependency issue. Ensure they are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I basically deleted and trashed the project created new one and did the same stuff I had mentioned earlier in my post and instead of throwing error after catch statement console log it and I am getting the result I expected. I really couldn't tell what was I doing wrong before. @jarmond the error I posted above, I accidentally included a dependency while changing something and caused the error I provided. Thanks everyone for looking into the issue.

Comment: Been a pleasure, welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the `promise()` function doesn't do what you expect it to do. It's worth noting, that you can actually also do the same thing with the standard Node.js `promisify` function.

```
import { DocumentClient } from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";
import { promisify } from "util";

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
...
const data = await promisify((cb) => docClient.query(params, cb))();
```

As @jarmod pointed out, there's probably something else going on though. I added some sidenotes to clarify some things that you may or may not already know.

##### Some sidenotes

Here are just some remarks which aren't entirely on topic but which can lead to confusion.

```
// don't do this, it doesn't do what you think it does.
throw new Error(`Failed query for ${id}`, err );

// this prints both a text and an object.
console.error(`Failed query for ${id}`, err);

// this throws just an error with a message
throw new Error(`Failed query for ${id}`);

// there is a 2nd argument which you can pass, which is an "options" parameter, which you can use to send a `cause` along.
throw new Error(`Failed query for ${id}`, { cause: err } );
```

*PS:More details about it can be found it [in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error).*

I haven't seen how you got it working without the promise, but if you did it like this, then it's not what you think.

```
try {
    const params = { ... };
    dynamoDB.query(params);

    // this point is always reached
    return "success"
}catch (err) { 
    // this point is never reached
}
```

Instead, without a promise, you would have to use a callback function.

```
const params = { ... };
dynamoDB.query(params, (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("success", data);
});
```

Comment: How will manually promisifying an SDK call help vs. the native promise support in the SDK?

Comment: @jarmod It shouldn't make any difference. However, the person who posted the question seems to indicate that it works without the `.promise()`, that makes it a useful experiment to create the promise manually by the means which I provided in my answer. By avoiding what appears to be broken, you can verify if that really is what is broken.

Comment: It doesn't work without the `.promise()` suffix. The OP's mistakenly assuming that the fact that the code continues to return "success" means that it succeeded, but it didn't.

Comment: @bvdb, same error as printed above with your answer as well

Comment: @Shailesh123 As @jarmod pointed out, you really need to take a look at that `err` object. Right now, you're not really printing that error, it's just hidden away. Also, what @jarmod is pointing out, is that you probably didn't test correctly when you tested it without the promise. Just to make sure, I added some pointers to my answer to verify those remarks. Because, once you take a look at that `err` message, it could be as simple as an incorrect endpoint configuration or missing keys.